# Indexing/Accessing MATLAB nested structure

Tags: matlab, indexing, matlab-struct

Hope, that I'm not creating a duplicate, but so far I didn't find the right answer for my problem.

Let's say, we have the following structure(s):

```
a(1).b = 1;
a(1).x.y = 2;

a(2).b = 3;
a(2).x.y = 4;
```

When I now try to get all values of b, I can do:

```
>> a(:).b

ans = 1
ans = 3
```

But how to this with the nested struct .x.y?

```
>> a(:).x.y
```

> Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 2 results.

Thanks for your help...!

Comment: Interesting to know that Octave support multiple consecutive indexing, so with octave you can use `[[a.x].y]` or `[a.x].y`.

Comment: Also if someone know why this has not be implemented in matlab: I'm interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just loop over the indices.

```
>> arrayfun(@(k) a(k).x.y, 1:numel(a))

ans =

     2     4
```

or:

```
>> struct2array(cell2mat(extractfield(a,'x')))

ans =

     2     4
```

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of ´arrayfun´ but didn't find the right way how to implement it.